# Best database/ETL tools for BI implementation with no direct access to source data (data report download only)

Tags: database, powerbi, etl

I'm an entry level data analyst for a medium sized franchisor overseeing ~100+ franchise locations.

I'm looking to implement a BI tool (such as Power BI), however we do not have direct access to any of our source data (no APIs or DB access). i.e. we must download our data in the form of reports from each of our 5+ IT platforms.

I'm currently using Excel and Power Query to convert these reports to a usable format for ad-hoc data analysis, however this is not an ideal solution for future BI requirements and historical data analysis work. I'm not sure the best method or tools to use to essentially create a new database from these reports (which are not always in a flat format).

Considering my situation, does anyone have any recommendations on any database platforms (i.e. MS Access, AWS Redshift, Azure, etc.) and/or ETL solutions so I could simply download the files and have them automatically "cleansed" and uploaded to a database?

Thank you

Comment: Recomendations like this are explicitly off-topic, per the [help].

Comment: Where can I go to ask such questions?